# VBA: Find word in string from ;-delimited cell

Tags: vba

I need a function to identify if a word from a ;-delimited cell exists in another ;-delimited cell. For example, my A1 cell may contain "Italy;Finland" or just "Finland". My B column contains multiple cells with countries, e.g. "Switzerland;Netherlands;Belgium;Finland;France".

I need a function to tell me whether or not Italy or Finland was found in the cells in the B-column and return TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Hello Macko what you are asking for is easy, just split the content of the cell into arrays and use the function match. But you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but maybe it will help you along the way.

```
Function FindSubstr(CellIn)

    Dim countries() As String

    countries = Split(CellIn, ";")
    FindSubstr = ""
    NewLine = ""
    For j = 0 To UBound(countries)
        '************************************************************************************
        '* Find the String in column B
        '************************************************************************************
        Set FindStat = Range("B:B") _
                    .Find(countries(j), LookIn:=xlValues)
        NewLine = vbLf
        If FindStat Is Nothing Then
            FindSubstr = FindSubstr + NewLine + countries(j) + " False"
        Else
            FindSubstr = FindSubstr + NewLine + countries(j) + " True"
        End If

    Next j

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still unable to get it to work. Maybe I should mention that I have a named range which can change value from e.g. "Spain" to "France;Italy;Spain" or "something else. If it were just one value, I'd go for the usual ISNUMBER(SEARCH()) approach.

Right now, I'd like to use a function such as the one above to do something like "=FindSubstr(Country_RFS_local, G20)" where Country_RFS_local is the named range with the country names, and G20 (or any other cell for that matter) contains the delimited countries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is worth you, assuming you use Sheet1

```
Function FindCountry() As Boolean
Dim Country As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2)
    Set Country = .Find(What:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        Lookat:=xlWhole)
End With

FindCountry = False
If Country.Value = "Italy" Or Country.Value = "Finland" Then
    FindCountry = True
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to get it to work exactly to my needs by slightly modifying your code, so thank you very much!

```
Function RetrieveKeys(Find_txt As String, In_txt As Range)

    Dim countries() As String

    countries = Split(Find_txt, ";")
    RetrieveKeys = ""
    For j = 0 To UBound(countries)

        Set FindStat = In_txt.Find(countries(j), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If FindStat Is Nothing Then
            RetrieveKeys = "FALSE"
        Else
            RetrieveKeys = "TRUE"
        End If
    Next j

End Function
```